# Is there a Windows 7 add-on that will put the PID in the title bar of a window?

Tags: windows-7

Occasionally I run many instances of something, like Chrome or Visual Studio. Rarely, but often enough to bug me, one of them gets hosed and starts to consume 100% CPU. I can fire up the task manager to see which process is using 100%, but if it just says chrome.exe or devenv.exe, I don't know which window is the culprit. I'd like to know before terminating the process, so I can activate the app and shut it down cleanly.

The best I've found so far is to use Process Explorer's feature where I can right click a process and say "bring to front". But I am curious as to whether there is an app that will put the PID(s) right in the title bar of the window so I can tell which window matches the process.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handle this situation, is if you have multiple running instances of the program and you are not sure which one is consuming the CPU usage is to open up Task Manager (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>) and right click on the first instance of the program in question in the first tab, **Applications** and then press **Go To Process** this will switch you to the process listing with the associated process highlighted, check if this was the one consuming the CPU usage, if not, go back and try a different program instance and repeat the procedure until you narrow down the offending process.

From here you can then **End Task** or investigate further, whatever you wish to do.  The same process can be applied if you wish to kill a process but are not sure of the process name; first select your application, right click Go to Process and the process name will then be revealed.

Best of luck :)

Comment: I didn't know there was a Go To Process option in Task Manager. That is cool. Still, it involves one extra step over what I am currently doing. Also, Process Explorer doesn't make you guess :) You should check it out if you haven't used it. It's awesome. Thanks for you prompt response, though. I learned something.

Comment: Cool, well up to you what you wish to use, at least this method doesn't use an external program. Yep I have seen it, it's pretty rad :)

Comment: Accepted yours because this is as active as this question is going to get, and I learned something. Close enough. :)